# Mavericks PHP versions issue

Tags: php

I just ran the command below to update PHP on my system (twice, forgot I ran it before).

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5
```

Output

```
Detected OS X Mavericks 10.9 All ok.
Get packager.tgz
Unpack packager.tgz
Please type in your password, as we want to install this into /usr/local
Password:
Start packager (may take some time)
downloading http://php-osx.liip.ch/install/5.5-10.8-frontenddev-latest.dat
downloading http://php-osx.liip.ch/install/5.5-10.8/frontenddev/5.5-10.8-frontenddev-5.5.27-20150710-221744.tar.bz2

Installing package 5.5-10.8-frontenddev into root /
Package 5.5-10.8-frontenddev is already installed at version 5.5.27-20150710-221744. You wanted to install version 5.5.27-20150710-221744.
```

However when I run `php --version` I get

```
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

which php tells me `/usr/bin/php`
```

How can I get my system to use 5.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php --version
```

If you want that php to become the default when you type php at the command line, run this:

```
echo "alias php='/usr/local/php5/bin/php'">>~/.bash_profile
```

then close your terminal and open a new one or run

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```